# socket.io with apache and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, websocket, socket.io

I would be implementing a notification in my web app.
The technologies on which the app is built is **Angularjs** **Apache** **PHP(For Api)**.
Our initial approach was to query the database every 10 seconds for any notification.
Is using **socket.io** beneficial in this scenario.?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the way you will implement it.

If you got only **1 or less** new datasets in 10 seconds you will save capacity by sending a message via socket.io to the client to pull the new data.

If you got **more than 1** new dataset in 10 seconds, the "pull every 10 seconds" will be better.

If you **dont know how much** new datasets will came up, you could the a mixed thing. Send a message to the client (via socket.io) to do the next pull. and then the client will pull timer-elapsion. if not, your timer will not pull the new data and will save network-traffic.